# Hyperterm Cannot find module error, when installing plugins

Tags: javascript, plugins, terminal, hyperterminal, hyperterm

I've installed a few plugins, but getting an error with `hyperterm-transparent-bg`

```
plugins: [
  'hyperterm-material',
  'hyperterm-transparent-bg',
  'hyperterm-blink'
],
```

The following don't work, and I keep getting a Cannot find module error, even though my paths are correct.

- [hyperterm-transparent-bg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-transparent-bg)

[image]

[image]

> bundle.js:1 Error: Cannot find module '/Users/leongaban/.hyper_plugins/node_modules/hyperterm-transparent-bg'
>       at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)

I re-installed Hyperterm and it doesn't look like it can rebuild the npm-debug.log file :(

**[Here is the gist to the last one I had saved off.](https://gist.github.com/leongaban/d7a806a6bd5c984745392b33d7eccbca)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this answer in their repo: https://github.com/dfrankland/hyper-transparent-bg/issues/9#issuecomment-284415902

Apparently it changed to this plugin instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-transparent

I used `yarn` instead of `npm` to install it: `yarn add npm i hyper-transparent`

Then in my .hyper.js config:

```
plugins: [
  'hyperterm-material',
  'hyperterm-blink',
  'hyper-transparent'
]
```

Got it working! Took me a sec to realize that the transparency controls where in the view menu of the OSX toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `shell` property in `.hyper.js` .

I have been having the same issue and got it fixed by setting the shell property after reading this https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1513#issuecomment-281414846

Comment: I did not try that, but I got https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-transparent to work